# CSS: Disponer tres fotos según un esquema concreto

Tags: php, html, jquery, css, layout

Mi web sobre música muestra en una página inicial tres fotos, correspondientes a los tres grupos cuya canción tiene mejor nota, según este código:

```
<div class="fotos oculto">

    <?php

        include("conexion.php");

        $contador = 0;

        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT titulo_cancion, nombre_autor, nota_media, ano  
                FROM listas NATURAL JOIN canciones NATURAL JOIN discos NATURAL JOIN publican NATURAL JOIN autores
                ORDER BY nota_media DESC
                LIMIT 3";

        $resultados = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

        while($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultados))
        {
            $titulo_cancion = utf8_encode($fila['titulo_cancion']);
            $nombre_autor = utf8_encode($fila['nombre_autor']);
            $nota_media = $fila['nota_media'];
            $ano = $fila['ano'];

            if(strpos($nombre_autor, ", The")) $nombre_autor_orden = "The ".substr($nombre_autor, 0, strpos($nombre_autor, ", The"));
            else $nombre_autor_orden = $nombre_autor;

            $recopilatorio = $ano;

            $contador++;

            echo '<div>';

                echo '<form class="cont-img-top3" data-prueba="prueba" method="post" action="index.php?fichero=recopilatorios.php">';

                    echo '<img class="img-top3" src="imagenes/autores/'.$nombre_autor.'.jpg">';
                    echo '<div class="num-top3" data-contador2="'.$contador.'">'.$contador.'</div>'; 
                    echo '<div class="text-top3"><span class="cancion-top3">'.$titulo_cancion.'</span>&nbspde&nbsp<span class="autor-top3">'.$nombre_autor_orden.'</span>&nbsp<span class="ano-top3">(<button class="boton-enlace" role="link" name="recopilatorio" value="'.$recopilatorio.'">'.$ano.'</button>)</span></div>';

                echo '</form>';

            echo '</div>';

        }

    ?>

    <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-decadas" type="submit">¡Vamos!</button>

    <form method="post" action="index.php?fichero=decadas.php">

        <div id="modal-decadas" class="modal fade" role="dialog">

            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">

                <div class="modal-content">

                    <div class="modal-header justify-content-center"><h5>Elige tu <span style="color: mediumvioletred">década</span> favorita</h5></div>

                    <div class="modal-body d-flex justify-content-center">

                        <?php

                            $decadas = array("1960", "1970", "1980", "1990", "2000");  

                            for($i = 0; $i < count($decadas); $i++) echo '<button class="btn btn-info d-block mx-1 mb-2" name="inicio_decada" value="'.$decadas[$i].'">'.$decadas[$i].'s</button>';

                        ?>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </form>

</div>
```

Esto se ve así (obviamente las fotos cambian según varíe la nota de las canciones, y no son del mismo tamaño, aunque procuro que sean rectangulares, más anchas que altas)...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

... tras aplicarle algo de CSS (espero haber incluido todas las clases de relevancia, si necesitáis alguna más, pedidla):

```
.cont-img-top3 {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.img-top3 {
    width: 600px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.num-top3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 30px;
    color: mediumvioletred;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 75px;
    font-family: 'Rock Salt', cursive;
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 4px pink;
    transition: all 0.25s ease;
}

.text-top3 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    background-color: powderblue;
    border: 2.5px solid lightblue;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.cancion-top3 {
    color: purple;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.autor-top3 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.ano-top3 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

Bien, lo que querría es que esto se dispusiera más o menos así, centrado en pantalla (porque sobre las fotos opera un script de jQuery que las agranda cuando se pasa el ratón sobre ellas; si la 1 o la 3 quedan muy pegadas al borde posiblemente se visualicen mal):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También necesitaría que ese espacio entre las tres fotos se mantuviera constante independientemente de cuáles fueran las fotos para evitar que el botón quede parcialmente oculto.

El "2" posiblemente lo desplace a la derecha de su foto, para que no quede parcialmente oculto; tampoco os preocupéis por eso.

Bien, supongo que esto requeriría operar con `float`, `absolute`, `relative`, etc. para dejarlo todo ordenadito, pero son conceptos de CSS que me resultan bastante opacos, así que si me echaseis una mano para saber por dónde empezar para luego dejarlo totalmente a mi gusto vía ensayo-error, os lo agradecería enormemente.

Comment: He reformulado la pregunta porque he cambiado el código para añadir un modal.

Comment: ¿Es muy complicado de hacer?

Answer (score 4):

Empecemos viendo como queda para después explicar como esta hecho y como puedes modificar lo a tu gusto

[image: Resultado]

Este seria el resultado final, Intente que se pareciera lo mas posible a tu esquema ya tu mismo podrás tocar bordes , colores , tamaños etc...

### ***EXPLICACION***

El código html seria este:

```
  <div class="padre">
    <div class="hijo"><img src="" alt=""></div>
    <div class="hijo"><img src="" alt=""></div>
    <div class="hijo"><img src="" alt=""></div>
    <button>Vamos!</button>
  </div>
```

1. div `.padre` para posicionar en el centro de la pagina y mover a
   gusto los divs de dentro.
2. div `hijo` posicionar en función del esquema para luego mostrar la imagen dentro.
3. Un botón para tu llamada a la acción.

Código CSS para cada elemento:

1. Para el div `.padre`

```
        .padre{
        width: 560px;
        height: 480px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%);}
```

Aplicamos un Ancho y alto luego centramos en la pagina.

2. Para los div `.hijo`

```
        .hijo{
        display: block;
        border: 5px solid skyblue;
        width: 304px;
        height: 204px;
        background: black;}

        .hijo img{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 304px;
        height: 204px;}
```

Los mostramos como bloques , agregamos un borde ,ancho y alto ( rectangular ) y un fondo para ver como queda. Lo mejor seria quitar el fondo ya que seria remplazado por la imagen.

Luego a las `img` que estan dentro les agregamos un `position=absolute` para posicionarlas correctamente dentro del div, luego les agregamos el mismo ancho y alto que el div para evitar que sobresalga del mismo.

3. Posicionamiento de los div `.hijo`

```
        .hijo:nth-child(1){
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        z-index: 6;}

        .hijo:nth-child(2){
        position: absolute;
        top: 45%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        right: 0px;
        z-index: 5;}

        .hijo:nth-child(3){
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
        left: 40%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        z-index: 4;}
```

A todos les agregaremos un `position=absolute` para poder posicionar dentro del div `.padre`.

- Al primero lo colocamos a la esquina superior izquierda.
- Al segundo lo posicionamos casi al centro del div pero no totalmente 
  ya que tu esquema muestra de la misma manera el contenedor.
- Al tercero lo posicionamos al final de todo el    contenedor
  `.padre`, y    a un `40%` de la izquierda para que quede    el efecto
  que deseas

  4. Boton Llamado a la accion:

```
        .padre button{
        position: absolute;
        padding: 8px 16px;
        border: 5px solid skyblue;
        background: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: skyblue;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        left: 25%;
    }
```

Le aplicamos estilos para darle forma y que se vea bien y lo posicionamos.

### ***Resultado Final***

```css
.padre{
    width: 560px;
    height: 480px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
.padre button{
    position: absolute;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    border: 5px solid skyblue;
    background: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: skyblue;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    left: 25%;
}
.hijo{
    display: block;
    border: 5px solid skyblue;
    width: 304px;
    height: 204px;
    background: black;
}
.hijo img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 304px;
    height: 204px;
}
.hijo:nth-child(1){
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 6;
}
.hijo:nth-child(2){
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 5;
}
.hijo:nth-child(3){
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 40%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    z-index: 4;
}
```

```html
  <div class="padre">
    <div class="hijo"><img src="" alt=""></div>
    <div class="hijo"><img src="" alt=""></div>
    <div class="hijo"><img src="" alt=""></div>
    <button>Vamos!</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta, Daniel. Ayer de noche estuve haciendo experimentos, y no he visto tu solución hasta esta mañana, así que voy a exponer en una respuesta a continuación lo que he hecho, a ver qué os parece. Luego intentaré comparar ambas propuestas para mejorar la mía.

Answer (score 0):

Esta noche, antes de ver la propuesta de Daniel, llegué a una solución que funciona en la pantalla de mi portátil pero que no tengo claro que sea adaptativa (seguramente no, aunque creo que si quiero que mi web se vea en un móvil o tableta la tendré que rediseñar -y simplificar mucho-):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bien, el asunto es que las imágenes no existen como tal las tres en el HTML, sino que proceden de una llamada a la BD:

```
echo '<img class="img-top3" src="imagenes/autores/'.$nombre_autor.'.jpg">';
```

Y van acompañadas de más información:

1) El puesto en el Top 3, que es lo que permite manipularlas vía jQuery gracias al atributo `data`:

```
echo '<div class="num-top3" data-contador2="'.$contador.'">'.$contador.'</div>';
```

2) La nota media de la canción, que inicialmente está oculta y se revela al pasar el ratón por encima de alguna foto:

```
echo '<div class="nota-top3 oculto">'.number_format($nota_media, 2, ',', '.').'</div>';
```

3) Toda la información que aparece en el cajetín: el título de la canción, el nombre del artista y el año, que a su vez es un botón disfrazado de enlace para acceder directamente al recopilatorio en que se encuentra esa canción:

```
echo '<div class="text-top3"><span class="cancion-top3">'.$titulo_cancion.'</span>&nbspde&nbsp<span class= "autor-top3">'.$nombre_autor_orden.'</span>&nbsp<span class="ano-top3">(<button class="boton-enlace" role="link" name="recopilatorio" value="'.$recopilatorio.'">'.$ano.'</button>)</span></div>';
```

Bien, todo esto va dentro de un contenedor que no es un `div` sino un `form`, debido al botón del que os acabo de hablar:

```
echo '<form class="cont-img-top3" data-prueba="prueba" method="post" action="index.php?fichero=recopilatorios.php">';

        //Imagen, número, nota e información varia sobre la canción             

echo '</form>';
```

Por alguna razón que no recuerdo, a su vez el `form` va dentro de un `div` sin atributos; quizá una recomendación de algún otro forero para... ahora mismo no sé muy bien el qué.

Fuera ya de la llamada a la BD va el botón, que a su vez hace referencia a un modal donde se despliegan las cinco décadas que abarca mi web, para acceder al menú principal (o a uno de los cinco menús principales, uno por década):

```
<button class="boton-vamos btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-decadas" type="submit">¡Vamos!</button>
```

Bien, el CSS:

1) Para el formulario contenedor:

```
.cont-img-top3 {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

Al final decidí ponerle `position: absolute;` después de hacer algunas pruebas con `relative`; ni idea de si es mejor o peor, me pareció lo más fácil: planto cada foto donde yo quiera y punto. El `display: inline-block;` está ahí porque debía de venir en la solución que encontré hace unas semanas gugleando para que todos los elementos (número, texto, etc.) se quedaran dentro del marco de la foto en la posición que quiero.

2) La imagen:

```
.img-top3 {
    height: 400px;
    width: 600px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

Dado que todas las imágenes tienen un aspecto similar, opté por darles tanto un ancho como un alto fijo, porque de lo contrario no se me ocurría cómo conservar el espacio en blanco entre ellas constante.

Bien, `.num-top3`, `.nota-top3` y `.text-top3` no tienen mucho interés para lo que nos ocupa, creo; veo que todas van con `position: absolute;`.

El script de jQuery que controla que cada foto (o más bien cada contenedor) tenga unas características propias (como que el número y la nota de la foto 2 aparezcan en orden opuesto a los de las demás); no es muy elegante:

```
$(function() 
{
    $('[data-contador2="1"]').css('left', '30px');
    $('[data-contador2="2"]').css('right', '50px');
    $('[data-contador2="3"]').css('left', '30px');

    $('[data-contador2="1"]').next().css('right', '40px');
    $('[data-contador2="2"]').next().css('left', '40px');
    $('[data-contador2="3"]').next().css('right', '40px');

    $('[data-contador2="1"]').parent().addClass('cont-img-1');
    $('[data-contador2="2"]').parent().addClass('cont-img-2');
    $('[data-contador2="3"]').parent().addClass('cont-img-3');
});
```

Las clases que se añaden mediante `parent().addClass()` a cada contenedor:

```
.cont-img-1 {
    margin-top: 75px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.cont-img-2 {
    top: 300px;
    left: 530px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.cont-img-3 {
    top: 610px;
    left: 140px;
    margin-bottom: 75px;
}
```

Y la chapucísima que hice con el botón para dejarlo ahí en medio:

```
.boton-vamos {
    margin-top: 517.5px;
    margin-left: 370px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

Creo que es todo. Ahora me falta analizar la propuesta de Daniel para intentar mejorar la mía.

Comment: dentro del cada div `.hijo` podrias crear un nuevo `<?php ?>` y poner el `echo` de cada imagen